Formal references for graph counting lemma
I'm trying to find a formal reference (paper or well-written lecture note) for graph counting lemma in order to use in an incomming paper. The version I want to find is the following:
Graph Counting Lemma. If $H$ is graph such that its vertices can be partitioned into $k$ independent sets $V_1,\ldots,V_k$ such that
$|V_i| = \ell$ for all $1 \le i \le k$ and either $(V_i,V_j)$ is an $\epsilon$-regular graph of density $d_{i,j} \gg \epsilon$ or $V_i \cup V_j$ is an independent set for all $1 \le i < j \le k$. Then the number of canonical copies of $H$ is
$$  \ell^k(1 - h\varepsilon)^k\prod_{u_iu_j \in E(H)}(d_{i,j} - \varepsilon) \le \# H's \le \ell^k\prod_{u_iu_j \in E(H)} (d_{ij} + \varepsilon).$$
Other forms like $|\# H's - \ell^k \prod_{u_i u_j \in E(H)} d_{i,j}| < C_k \epsilon \ell^k   $ also works.
There are several references I found.

https://www.ime.usp.br/~spschool2016/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Komlos-Shokoufandeh-Simonovits-Szemeredi.pdf (Theorem 15 - this is for quasi-random graph)
https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/en/personen/schacht/2010/reg_survey.pdf (Theorem 18, this is something converse since we fix constant $C_k$ first.)
https://ti.inf.ethz.ch/ew/lehre/GA10/lec-regularity-new-nopause.pdf (This is good but just a slide)

Thank you.
